# How use mouse control with pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

What are the commands for mouse control in pygame? How do I control them? If a person clicks the left button on a mouse is it possible for animation to be played on a pygame screen? I'm running python 2.6 under windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible.
You can do this in the event loop you probably have in your python script:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        run_your_animation()
```

Or, if you don't have any other events (you probably won't use this because you most likely have an event to quit the program / close the window):

```
if pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN in [event.type for event in pygame.event.get()]:
    run_your_animation()
```

An alternative will be using pygame.mouse.get_pressed(), but this will return True if you hold too and not only if you hit the button.

Answer (score 2):

Get the status of the buttons and the position of the mouse:

```
(left, middle, right) = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
(x, y) = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
```